# "woocommerce_form_field()" function having issues after latest woocommerce update

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I have this custom code that was working without issue prior to the latest update of woocommerce, but after the update, the HTML markup in the options field is now showing on the live site. TO be clear, the 
 tag is now showing whereas before it added the line break it was supposed to do.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'checkout_outofstockoption' );

function checkout_outofstockoption( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Option if product is not available') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'outofstockoption', array(
        'type'          => 'radio',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('We try our best to ensure accurate stock levels. However, in the event that your product is out of stock, please let us know how you would like us to proceed:<br />'),
        'options'       => array('Substitute'=>' Substitute with a similar item of equal or greater value (if no suitable substitute is available a credit will be issued)<br />','Credit'=>' Receive store credit<br />'),
        'required'      => true
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'outofstockoption' ));

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Was there something different to do that changed in the new update?

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

In version [4.2.1](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/4.2.1/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2785) they add the function [esc_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) to the option text.
Here the link to version [4.2.0](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/4.2.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2800) for comparison.

Comment: This seams to be the cause to this issue, it has messed up some of my custom code as well. Do we have any work around?